# What is the efficient way to create a Demo version of web application?

Tags: api, web-applications, frontend, backend

I am researching on the demo version/account of the application for the users. The demo account is a read-only account to prospects so that they can view a fully functional demo account. Instead of signing up or paying for the application to see what it looks like, they can view what the service and what are the functionalities without signing up for it.

It could be based on static data (and doesn't have to be dynamically generated).

Based on my research, I have concluded a few things that can be helpful to create a demo application and keeping the persistency of the demo application with the original application:

- We can have separate routes for demo application something like `app.com/demo/dashboard` or `app.com/dashboard?demo=1`. With the separate route, we have to use separate components because I don't want to entangle the demo components with the original components because it has lots of authentication logic, API calls and other stuff. With this approach comes the problem of keeping the persistency of Demo application UI with the actual application.

To overcome this, I can use the same styling for multiple components but not the structure. So with time, this will become cumbersome to keep the structure in sync.

So I am looking for general answers for:
What is the most efficient way to create a demo version of the application?
What data to use?
How to keep the components persistent. (For that, maybe we can create a Git workflow to make sure engineers update the structure of Demo UI whenever they update the structure of original UI)

I hope this pseudo code convey my thought process

[image: Pseudo code]

One of the demo web application example is: https://demo.pritunl.com/